# Data.table to shift one column down and fill with NA

Tags: r, data.table

I am trying to shift one column of a dataframe down by 1 row.

I convert my characters to a data frame

```
final_forecasting <- read.csv(textConnection(forecasts), col.names = c("date", "prediction"))
```

and then I try to use the shift function from the data.table package:

```
x <- setDF(shift(final_forecasting))[]
```

I want to just shift down the "prediction" column one row. However I cannot seem to finish it. I would also like to use the `fill` function to fill in the single `NA` value as `1`.

One attempt `x <- setDF(shift(final_forecasting["prediction"]))[]` .

Data:

```
forecasts <- c("2019-03-08 04:59:00,1", "2019-03-08 05:59:00,-1", "2019-03-08 06:59:00,-1", 
"2019-03-08 07:59:00,1", "2019-03-08 08:59:00,1", "2019-03-08 09:59:00,1", 
"2019-03-08 10:59:00,1", "2019-03-08 11:59:00,-1", "2019-03-08 12:59:00,1", 
"2019-03-08 13:59:00,1")
```

EDIT:

Another attempt:

```
x <- setDF(shift(final_forecasting, n = 1, fill = NA, type = "shift", give.names = TRUE))[]
```

Comment: not sure, but `dplyr`'s `lead()` or `lag()` (forgetting which shifts up v down) might work for the shift part..

Comment: I know of some other functions, and there has been one or two similar questions to shifting certain columns. I was just hoping to get a `data.table` approach.

Comment: you might want to read the documentation and vignettes. `setDT(final_forecasting)[, final_forecasting := shift(prediction, fill=1)]`

Answer (score 2):

If I get you right, I think what you need is to just define well your data.table with `setDT`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(final_forecasting)
```

And then use `shift` with your desired columns:

```
final_forecasting[,.(date = shift(date),prediction = shift(prediction))]
                  date prediction
1:                <NA>         NA
2: 2019-03-08 05:59:00         -1
3: 2019-03-08 06:59:00         -1
4: 2019-03-08 07:59:00          1
5: 2019-03-08 08:59:00          1
6: 2019-03-08 09:59:00          1
7: 2019-03-08 10:59:00          1
8: 2019-03-08 11:59:00         -1
9: 2019-03-08 12:59:00          1
```

Comment: Thanks, this is almost it but I am just trying to shift the column "prediction" down and leave the "date" column as it is.

Comment: Which `final_forecasting[,.(date = date, prediction = shift(prediction))]` does so.

Answer (score 1):

```
library(data.table)
setDT(final_forecasting)
final_forecasting[, prediction := shift(prediction, fill = 1)]

#                   date prediction
# 1: 2019-03-08 05:59:00          1
# 2: 2019-03-08 06:59:00         -1
# 3: 2019-03-08 07:59:00         -1
# 4: 2019-03-08 08:59:00          1
# 5: 2019-03-08 09:59:00          1
# 6: 2019-03-08 10:59:00          1
# 7: 2019-03-08 11:59:00          1
# 8: 2019-03-08 12:59:00         -1
# 9: 2019-03-08 13:59:00          1
```

Now if you want to convert your data back to a plain `data.frame` just run:

```
setDF(final_forecasting)
```

Or do it directly in base R:

```
final_forecasting$prediction <- c(1L, final_forecasting$prediction[-1])
```

Data:

```
forecasts <- c("2019-03-08 04:59:00,1", "2019-03-08 05:59:00,-1", "2019-03-08 06:59:00,-1", 
"2019-03-08 07:59:00,1", "2019-03-08 08:59:00,1", "2019-03-08 09:59:00,1", 
"2019-03-08 10:59:00,1", "2019-03-08 11:59:00,-1", "2019-03-08 12:59:00,1", 
"2019-03-08 13:59:00,1")
final_forecasting <- read.csv(textConnection(forecasts), col.names = c("date", "prediction"))
```